# Why $y^T(X \hat{\beta}) = (X\hat{\beta})^Ty$

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors, least-squares

In the article, [Derivation: Ordinary Least Squares Solution and Normal Equations](https://theclevermachine.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/derivation-of-ols-normal-equations/)

I don't understand how [image] becomes [image] in the equation [image]

It seems no [matrix transpose rules](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/sapirmv/msapir/prtranspose.html) can apply to it to get the result.

Comment: if a matrix is 1 by 1, meaning it is a single number, it is its own transpose

Comment: You mean  $y^T(X \hat{\beta})$ is 1 by 1?

Comment: Yes. It’s another way of writing the dot product of $y$ and $X\hat\beta$.